# Trouble with advanced .htaccess redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm migrating a custom coded blog over to Wordpress, and have to set up a redirect that will handle all of the blog posts.

I need to redirect from this:

/oldblogdirectory/Old_Blog_Posts_Looked_Like_This.htm

to:

/newblogdirectory/new-blog-posts-look-like-this/

Any ideas on the regex for a redirect like this?

Comment: your question is too vague. there should be some identifier in the old URL which we can pass to the new URL, e.g. post id, date/time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gumbo's approach is certainly the way to do it. I made two test directories:

```
oldblogdir/archives/blog_posts_look_like_this.htm
newblogdir/archives/blog-posts-look-like-this
```

And the following RewriteRules redirect successfully. They are only slightly changed to Gumbo's proposal:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(oldblogdir/archives/[^_]*)_(.*) $1-$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^oldblogdir/archives/(.*?)\.htm$ newblogdir/archives/$1 [R,NC,L]
```

Note that the `[N]` causes the .htaccess file to be re-evaluated until the RegEx no longer matches. Therefore you should put it at the very top of the file.

Comment: That will cause an infinite recursion.

Comment: I don't see why. Can you give an example URL that would cause an infinite recursion?

Answer (score 2):

Try this [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(oldblogdirectory/[^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*) /$1-$2-$3 [N]
RewriteRule ^(oldblogdirectory/[^_]*)_(.*) /$1-$2
RewriteRule ^oldblogdirectory/(.+)\.htm$ /newdirectory/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

But for the uppercase to lowercase conversion you’ll either need a mapping like the [internal `tolower` function](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) or you use PHP for both.

Comment: @SerpicoLugNut: Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: When I use it, it doesn't produce the desired effect of redirecting the old posts location to the new. I am placing this in my root .htaccess. For reference, the site structure is this:
old:
mydomainname.com/oldblogdir/archives/old_blog_posts_look_like_this.htm
new:
mydomainname.com/newblogdir/archives/new-blog-posts-look-like-this/

and I am modifying the .htaccess file located here:
mydomainname.com/.htaccess

Comment: It's actually clever to replace two underscores in the first rule and an eventually single one in the second, but then the single underscore in the second rule would have to be optional. Otherwise the rules won't match if there's an **even number** of underscores (or no underscore).

Comment: This works, except if there's no underscore in the old url. ;)